# Difference between ways to use gets method

Tags: ruby, input, stdout, stdin, chomp

I saw two ways to use `gets`, a simple form:

```
print 'Insert your name: '
name = gets()
puts "Your name is #{name}"
```

and a form that drew my attention:

```
print 'Insert your name: '
STDOUT.flush
name = gets.chomp
puts "Your name is #{name}"
```

The second sample looks like perl in using the `flush` method of the default output stream. Perl makes explicit default output stream manipulating; the method `flush` is a mystery to me. It can behave different from what I'm inferring, and it uses `chomp` to remove the new line character.

What happens behind the scenes in the second form? What situation is it useful or necessary to use the second form?

Comment: You'll sometimes see `gets.to_i` or `gets.to_f`.  There's no need for `chomp` here because, more generally, `"123cat".to_i => 123`, `"1.23dog".to_f => 1.23`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Flushing" the output ensures that it shows the printed message before it waits for your input; this may be just someone being certain unnecessarily, or it may be that on certain operating systems you need it. Alternatively you can use `STDOUT.sync = true` to [force a flush after every output](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D). (You may wonder, "Why wouldn't I always use this?" Well, if your code is outputting a lot of content, repeatedly flushing it may slow it down.)

`chomp` removes the newline from the end of the input. If you want the newline (the result of the user pressing "Enter" after typing their name) then don't `chomp` it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at some [Github code](https://github.com/search?l=ruby&o=desc&q=%22stdout.flush%22&s=indexed&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) I can see that `STDOUT.flush` is used mostly for server-side/multi-threaded jobs, and not in everyday use.

Generally speaking, when you want to accept input from the user, you'd want to use `gets.chomp`. Just remember, no matter what the user enters, Ruby will ALWAYS interprete that as a string.

To convert it to an integer, you need to call `to_i`, or `to_f` for a float. You don't need `chomp` in these cases, since `to_i` or `to_f` removes the "\n" automatically. There are a lot of subtle things going on implicitly as you'll see, and figuring them out is simply a matter of practice.

Comment: `to_i` and `to_f` do not *remove* the trailing line-ending, they ignore it since they're only concerned with digits, or digits and a decimal.

Answer (score 1):

I've rarely seen someone use STDOUT.flush except in mutli-threading. Also it makes things confusing, defeating the whole purpose of writing elegant code.